# Props not updating on store change - Reactjs/Redux

Tags: reactjs, redux

When retrieving data from an API and updating store, the props of my component are not updated.
It works correctly when calling the 'getGames' method, but not the 'getGame' method.

I know the action/reducer is functional as this method woks in other components. 
Additionally I know the action is being called (redux dev tools).

Component:

```
class Dashboard extends Component {
  static propTypes = {
    games: PropTypes.array.isRequired,
    game: PropTypes.object,
    getGames: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
    getGame: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
  };

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.openGamePanel = this.openGamePanel.bind(this);

    this.state = {
      rightPanelOpen: false,
      gameid: null,
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.props.getGames();
  }

  openGamePanel(game) {
    this.props.getGame(game.id);

    this.setState({
      gameid: game.id,
    });
  }

  check() {
    console.log(this.props);
  }

  toggleRightPanel() {
    this.setState({
      rightPanelOpen: !this.state.rightPanelOpen,
    });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <Fragment>
        <Map games={this.props.games} />
        <UIPanelLeft
          games={this.props.games}
          check={() => this.check()}
          handleOpenGamePanel={this.openGamePanel}
        />
        {this.props.game ? (
          <GamePanel game={this.props.game} key={this.props.game.id} />
        ) : (
          <div></div>
        )}
      </Fragment>
    );
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
  games: state.games.games,
  game: state.game,
  location: state.location,
});

export default connect(mapStateToProps, { getGames, getGame })(Dashboard);
```

Comment: I think you would need to share more code, it does not seem to have any obvious issues in this view. The only thing which perhaps may be an issue with the double nested `games.games` and perhaps a single game is not going into the correct location.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved:

I was pulling state.game rather than state.games.game from the store.

RIP 90 mins of my life.